# Please help me free this dynamically allocated array

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, free

```
row = n + 1;
col = n + 1;
//used n+1 and i=-1 to avoid segmentation faults

board = malloc(row*sizeof(char *));
for(i=-1;i<row;i++)
{       
    board[i] = malloc(col*sizeof(char));
    if(board[i] == NULL)
    {
        printf("Out of memory");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

for(i=-1; i < n+1; ++i)
{
    free(board [i]);
}
free(board);
```

When I try to free this array in run time, my compiler goes berserk, please explain, thank you.

Comment: which is the line of `free` that goes berserk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

arrays cannot have negative index in C.

at the line: `for(i = -1; i < row;  i++)`

I am very sure, there is an off by one error here, where `free` is freeing one extra block that was not `malloc()`ed at the end, and you must be getting a segfault error.

Comment: I am unsure if the negative index is a compile error or not (don't think so since `*(ptr - 1)` is valid), but when @user assigns to board[-1] there is definitely going to be undefined behaviour. @user, listen to this guy, and please, never try to index into an array with a negative number. :)

Answer (score 0):

malloc returns void pointer, you must cast it. Also minimum index is zero in C.

```
    board = (char**)malloc(row*sizeof(char *));
    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {       
        board[i] = (char*)malloc(col*sizeof(char));
        if(board[i] == NULL)
        {
        printf("Out of memory");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: NEVER (NEVER) cast return of `malloc` in C.

Comment: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)

Comment: wow I did not know that, but I think it is more readable. thanks for the answer